# DialogFragment exit animation showing empty white screen

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation, fragmentmanager, navcontroller

I have a DialogFragment with this code in order to animate when it exits:

```
override fun dismiss() {
       dismissListener?.invoke()
       exitAnimation?.let {
            val animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), it)
            animation.setAnimationListener(object : AnimationAdapter {

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                    callDismiss()
                }

            })
            view?.startAnimation(animation)
        } ?: callDismiss()
    }

    private fun callDismiss() {
        super.dismiss()
    }
```

exitAnimation defaults to a slide out animation.

However I noticed that it won't always show the back fragment, I have certain path of screens where no matter what I do, it seems to always shows a background white screen when animating instead of the backward fragment.

I don't know if this is because I have something like:

A B C D, where D is the DialogFragment, but A B C are part of a NavigationController / NavigatorFragment and D is not part of the navigation graph and is started from a FragmentTranscation from C's `parentFragmentManager`

I have tested in several ways, like sending the activity's supportFragmentManager but it seems that white screen is always visible.

I want the background fragment to be visible as when using the same fragmentmanager.

Comment: are you using a Navigation graph for fragments?

Comment: A DialogFragment doesn't change the previous Fragment at all. Please show your code for where you add your DialogFragment.

Comment: Navigation Graph is used for fragments A B C, C uses parentFragmentManager to push a DialogFragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just needed to make DialogFragment window transparent background.